# Capture error or rejected records while loading data from spark df to snowflake table

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have written a spark code which writes the dataframe into snowflake table.

**Code Snippet:**

```
val data = Seq(("1", "product12345678", "20000"), ("2", "product2", "30000"), ("3", "product3", "40000"))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val dfFromRDD1 = rdd.toDF()
dfFromRDD1.write.format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake").options(sfOptions).option("dbtable", "product").mode(SaveMode.Append).save()
```

**Table Structure:**

```
create or replace table product(
id int,
name varchar(8),
price int);
```

But due to some data mismatch issue wrt snowflake table, Im getting below error while writing df to snowflake.

**Error Message:**

> 23/09/27 13:20:18 ERROR package$: Fail to write in 1.21 seconds at
> 2023-09-27T13:20:18.565 23/09/27 13:20:18 ERROR StageWriter$: Error
> occurred while loading files to Snowflake: java.sql.SQLException:
> Status of query associated with resultSet is FAILED_WITH_ERROR.
> Results not generated. java.sql.SQLException: Status of query
> associated with resultSet is FAILED_WITH_ERROR. Results not generated.
> at
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SFAsyncResultSet.getRealResults(SFAsyncResultSet.java:127)

Actual error not being shown in an error message. To see the exact error I have to check the Query history in Snowflake UI. And the issue is name field can not hold more than 8 characters.

**Expectation:**
I want to filter out such invalid records causing an issue and then write into snowflake.

Using below versions for snowflake connector:

> `snowflake-jdbc-3.13.14.jar , spark-snowflake_2.11-2.9.3-spark_2.4.jar`

Could you please suggest, how should I handle it?

Comment: So what's the actual error you are seeing in Snowflake, what's the code you are running, what's the table definition you're writing to? Please update your question with enough information for someone to be able to help you (all as editable text, not images)

Comment: Data mismatch means your target table schema doesn't match the dataframe schema. You can probably skip them using [continue_on_error](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use#additional-options) but you might have inconsistent data in the target table.

Comment: @NickW, Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question with necessary details

Comment: @Sergiu, Thank you for your input. I have tried continue_on_error option and it skips an error record as expected for this usecase.

Is there anyway to capture an error records? so we can keep it somewhere to debug more.

Comment: Just a thought but if this process is effectively running a COPY INTO statement then it may be possible to retrieve the errors using VALIDATE: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate

Comment: Yeah, would be helpful so exploring this option as well. 
It would be better if there is anyway to extract error records from spark df itself